# How to create a DataSet from RDD using Case Class with composed columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset, rdd

Hi guys i using Spark/Scala 2.4.4 and have an RDD[Map(String, String)] with Persons... the rows are like this:

```
rdd = Map(
(FirstName -> "Michael")
(SecondName -> "Jackson")
)
```

I created a case class like this:

```
case class Person(FirstName: String, SecondName: String) {
    val FullName = FirstName + SecondName
}
```

how can i convert this RDD to a Dataset[Person], and it's possible to generate FullName column when the class are instantiated or i need to run withcolumn?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to expand the map into two columns and cast the rows as `Person`.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(Map(
    ("FirstName" -> "Michael"),
    ("SecondName" -> "Jackson")
)))

val df = rdd.toDF("person").select("person.FirstName", "person.SecondName").as[Person]
```

Then you can get the FullName using `map`, for example:

```
df.map(r => r.FullName).show
+--------------+
|         value|
+--------------+
|MichaelJackson|
+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but can i map FullName as a column instead of need to map all the time i need? Or just if i make df.withColumn("FullName", concat_ws("FirstName","SecondName"))?

Comment: Yes, I think using withColumn and Spark SQL functions is better than relying on class methods.

Comment: Thanks i am worried about performance of withColumn but i think that't will be my best option hehehe